# 1 x 3 splitter with connecting cables for Wi-Fi RF calibration

Tags: signal, cables, wifi, signal-processing

So i have a 1 x 3 splitter, where i transmit a signal s(t) as follows
[image]

The purpose of the following setup is to find the different delays in each RF receiver (Cable->LNA->VGA->ADC). A clearer picture might be this

[image]

> My question is simply, do the connecting wires introduce any "multipath" ? In other words, might the transmitted signal be received in delayed versions ? Or can i be sure that only one copy of my signal s(t) is being received.
>
> P.S: I have no experience in splitter and connecting cable usages, but my application requires me to know the different delays across each path "Cable->LNA->VGA->ADC". Any advices or alternatives are highly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There will be relections from any impedance discontinuities, how severe depends on how precise the connector impedance's match the cables, amplifiers and splitters.

You might find getting some circulators useful or at least adding some pads between stages to improve the isolation.

The VNA is the right tool for this kind of thing, as it can usually read out group delay directly in ns as well as measuring S11,S22 directly which is useful for checking SWR.

I hope the sample clock to your ADCs is delay equalised?

Comment: Hello @Dans Mills, first of all thank you so much for your useful response. Second, is a VNA easily available and afordable to buy ? Third, yes the ADCs are runned by the same crystal oscillator.

Comment: But are the pcb net lengths to the ADC clock pins from the oscillator equal? A used VNA is anything from maybe a grand or so up, but they are hireable from the usual test equipment rental houses. RF Metrology is an artform, and you may want to get some help from someone who knows what they are doing, good data up in the microwave bands demands serious attention to detail (Things like torque wrenching the connectors to the correct level, and did you know most SMA connectors are only rated for a very few matings if you need them to meet design specs).